# What is the longest known time between the commission of an offence and conviction in English legal history?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-history

In England & Wales, the former Labour peer Lord Ahmed was recently [jailed for sexual offences](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-south-yorkshire-60260113) he was convicted of dating from the early 1970s. This 50+ year gap seems quite long, although obviously for serious sexual offences there is no limitation on prosecution.

What is the longest known time between the commission of an offence and the conviction of the perpetrator in **England & Wales** ?  Is Lord Ahmed's the longest?

Answer (score 5):

### At least 56 years

[Anthony Sawoniuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Sawoniuk) was convicted in 1999 of 2 murders committed while he was a member of the SS. I cannot find the exact date of the offenses but they were before he deserted in November 1944.

There may be longer ones but on seeing your question, Nazi war crimes popped into my head as something easy to check. If the actual answer is some obscure crime from the 19th century, I don’t know how you’d find it.

Comment: Per [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20080211173904/http://www.timesonline.co.uk/tol/news/uk/article1081468.ece), the murders he was convicted of were committed in 1942, though again it doesn't give an exact date.

Comment: Germany tops that: In late 2021, a secretary was charged with assisting 11000 murders, all happening before 2045 - and as a result, happened more than 76 years ago. Incidently, because she was 18 in 1945, the trial happens in front of the youth court. And since 2011 / 2016, it is deemed sufficient to have been present in a concentration camp and to have known that the killings happened to have assisted in the murder. It isn't ex-post-facto law, just the interpretation where the line is changed.

Comment: @Trish Do you mean 1945, rather than 2045?

Comment: yes, autocorrect messed that up

Comment: What a disgusting vindictive contrivance to miscarry the interests of justice.

Comment: @JosephP. Why do you think it’s just that if you can conceal mass murder for long enough, you don’t deserve punishment?

Comment: Most legal systems recognize a principle of limitations, of after a certain time, letting sleeping dogs lie. And the contrivances and exceptions made in altering the way of interpretation of facts. There are much more pressing and current war crimes being perpetrated by the state of Israel, by Saudi Arabia, and by the United States all over the world. But the Holocaust lobby prefers to contort the world's legal systems to facilitate vindictively and cruelly going after 94 year olds. How responsible or influential can one have been at 18 as a secretary anyway?

Comment: Unlike the current and recent wars in Yemen, Iraq, Ukraine or Afghanistan for those prosecuting them, WWII was a total war with the survival and dignity of all the societies on all sides at stake. In that context there is immense pressure to join, contribute and do one's duty. In a total war context that does not mean questioning orders but following them even if you don't agree. Conscientious objection or desertion in a total war context would certainly gain greater opprobrium socially but I think is also less noble and selfless morally. In any event it's a conversation that's possible to

Comment: Have once Barack Obama, Hillary Clinton, Joe Biden, GWB, and Tony Blair are prosecuted for their war crimes but downright silly until then.

Comment: I'm someone who finds it unpleasant to speak with someone who says they do something as mundane as  maintain aircrafts on US military installations. But the zeal of holocaust avengers is disproportionately, unhealthy, and disingenuously applied.

Comment: @JosephP. As far as I know, no jurisdiction has a statute of limitations on murder, genocide or war crimes.

Comment: Really? IANAL but I always thought there was a statute of limitations on pretty much everything in America including murder and had understood it as sort of a foundational principle of the legal system that liability for actions is not infinite and nobody should have to live in the ambiguous shadow of their actions for their lifetime. Nonetheless, you still conveniently disregard so many other things I've said. Do you see Mr. Netanyahu on trial for his much more recent, substantial, and consequential crimes? If not, then one must ask and  address why that is before having this conversation.

Comment: What  jurisprudential principle of justice exactly is it that exonerates netanyahu, Clinton, Bush, Blair, Obama, and Boden for their war crimes?

Comment: @JosephP. The fact that none of them has ever been charged with war crimes. Nor, on the basis of what is publicly known, is there any evidence to support such a charge. Heads of State/Government engaging in military action are not war crimes.

Comment: Ordering illegal wars / wars of aggression are not crimes? Didn't the Nuremberg trials declare it the Cardinal crime? Are you saying that Hitler wouldn't have been tried for anything if he'd not offed himself?